# Movie about a crashed spaceship where an alien devours crewmembers, and the crew fight back and kill it?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I only saw this movie once when I was a kid so I can only recall some things about the movie and none of the actors. The film is probably late 70's to late 80's era; I don't know the exact year.

It opens with a spaceship crew in cryopods or the like. The main character wakes up to see a speaker on the stasis pods and another crewman telling her to stay quiet or the alien will eat her. Sure enough, another crewman wakes up, a female I think, and a black gorilla-looking alien breaks open the cryopods and devours her.  All of them can hear this on the speakers in their stasis pods.

The majority of the movie is them trying to escape and kill that monster. Near the end, our main character discovers that the gorilla alien was sent by these white aliens that look like your classic alien. She tracks them down to their underground base to find one of her crewmates is being dissected with a half cut open skull revealing her brain. She tells our main character to turn around until she sees an alien and blasts it in the head.

The movie ends with our main character and one of the male crew embracing each other, cutting to the credits.

Comment: It's far too recent a film, but this sounds a bit like [*Pandorum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandorum)

Comment: Yah the stasis pods in the film I'm thinking of were more like planet of the apes and less like what you see in pandorum.